# PHP-FPM and capistrano, "No input file specified"

Tags: linux, deployment, nginx, capistrano, php

I use capistrano to deploy new versions of a website to servers that run nginx and php-fpm, and sometimes it seems like php-fpm gets a bit confused after deployment and expects old files to exist, generating the "No input file specified" error. I thought it could have had something to do with APC, which I uninstalled, but I realize the process doesn't get as far as checking stuff with APC.

Is there a permission friendly way to tell php-fpm that after deployment it needs to flush its memory (or similar), that I could use? I don't think I want to do sudo restarts.

rlimit_files isn't set in php-fpm.conf, and ulimit -n is 250000.

Comment: This is an issue with your nginx config, please share your nginx config for this server ( the fpm one )

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Since it works flawlessly until sometimes when I deploy, I doubt there's an error with the config

Comment: In my case reloading php-fpm was the fix for this. `sudo service php7.0-fpm reload` or whatever version you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx has it's own rather aggressive filecache. It's worse when NFS is involved since that has it's own cache as well. Tell capistrano to restart nginx after deployment.

It can also be an issue with your configuration as Mohammad suggests, but then a restart shouldn't fix the issue, so you can tell the two apart.

Comment: Restarting nginx after deploy doesn't do it for me :(